# PayPal : Autoupdate Subscriptions (Recurring Payments)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am having WebPayments Standard account and I've integrated subscription buttons in my site. The subscription is for 6 months for an year. Eventhough, the subscription was successful, I am not able to retrieve the status of the payments and display it in my application. Is it possible to track the subscriptions using WebPayments Standard?

If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) to update your database, and then your application can query your own database.  Some of the Recurring Payment API's also work to get information back on subscriptions assuming the subscription profiles start with an I- instead of an S-.  You can look at some of the Recurring Payment API's [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#wpp) and check them out.